# Can I install 2 or even more mavens in my computer?

Tags: eclipse, maven

For some reasons, my computer has 3 Eclipse IDE instances on it, Indigo, Juno and Kepler.

Indigo is used in real developing, Juno is for program execising, Kepler is being used in another project. Each of them contains a maven project.

But, there is only 1 maven in my computer, and 3 eclipse instances are now sharing it.

And these are errors keep coming which associate with maven, sometimes I need to clear some directories in maven or modify some maven config files. That makes me worry about whether one change would affect other maven project in other eclipses.

So I decide to isolate different eclipse, give each eclipse its own maven and tomcat and so on.
Could that be possible? if it so, how should config the system path and other relevant configuration??
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's most important to have an up-to-date installation of m2e in all eclipse version but why do you need several Eclipse installation why not using a single one like Kepler.

Comment: Personally, I would like to use Kepler, and I do use Kepler when I am working witk my own small maven project. But my company has regulation that we should unify our IDE version(they choose v3.7), for preventing unnecessary unexpected and unknown errors during developing

Answer (score 2):

> Could that be possible?

Yes its completely possible.

> how should config the system path and other relevant configuration?

Goto *Window -> Preference -> Maven -> Installations -> Add* and add a new installation of maven and you can switch between any installation of maven within the eclipse

> And these are errors keep coming which associate with maven, sometimes I need to clear some directories in maven or modify some maven config files. That makes me worry about whether one change would affect other maven project in other eclipses

Firstly this shouldn't happen unless and until you have different settings and profiles set-up in your `settings.xml`. So, prior to configuring multiple mavens, first debug why the maven settings get distubred in the other projects.

**EDIT**

If you are working with different maven settings ( and by settings I mean different repositories setup for each project and different server configurations that you want to keep isolated with other projects ) make use of [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) . Although, the real purpose of profiles is building for different environments ( like for dev/test/production ) you can use these profiles for building your different projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have installed 2 mavens in my pc already. Each eclipse has its own Maven, and I set different repositories and system path for each of them.  No unexpected errors occured so far.  Let see what will happen, and I will show them here after errors happened.